# How to detect if browser supports CSP on the server?

Tags: browser, server, content-security-policy

I have a server `helper.com` that serves responses to `GET` requests with custom CSP, e.g.:

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors https://my.com;`

The idea is that only `my.com` can include the widget from `helper.com`.

This works fine in modern browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

The question is, how can I reliably exclude browsers that don't support CSP?

That is all the IE family (?), very old versions of good browsers, legacy browsers, even NN if someone happens to use it?

The technical reason is that if the user has a session cookie on `helper.com`, I plan to serve user's confidential information and I'm worried about cases where someone uses e.g. IE, is logged in, and some hackers will create `hacker.com` that tries to fetch stuff from `helper.com` via ajax or script tag or font resource or image to canvas and steal user's confidential data.

In sort, if I serve CSP, I want to be sure it will be applied by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

What I would have done is the set of following steps:

1. Generally browsers send `user-agent` on the request headers. And There is no way to change the `user-agent` header sent by the browser from client side code. So, I would have used that value on web server side in order to decide which browser I am dealing with. ref: [understanding user-agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Which_part_of_the_user_agent_contains_the_information_you_are_looking_for)
2. Then based on the [browser and CSP headers compatibility matrix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Browser_compatibility) I would have known if I should allow/disallow this browser. Off course I know exactly which CSP headers support I require for my website.
3. For the disallowed browsers I would serve the `browser-not-supported.html` to say or for others I would have proceeded further.
4. I would have also added some trivial JS code in my `index.html` or other html pages in order to not make requests if this browser is not supporting the exact CSP headers, which I need for my site.
5. Also, I would have added the old browsers compatible headers on my http response like `X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"` which will serve our specific purpose in case the browser does not honor/understand the CSP headers.

Comment: Users can **easily** change their user agent, which effectively invalidates this entire response.  Remember the Golden Rule: *Never trust user input*

Comment: Let's assume well-meaning users :) The original question was to distinguish between a modern user (good browser, can be trusted to enforce CSP) and legacy user (old browser, no hope to be secure). Both user classes are allowed to log in, but on the earlier should be allowed to use the new, cross-site functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t really what CSP does. CSP doesn’t protect the site from malicious users; it protects users from compromised web sites. Your best bet is some form of server authentication to determine whether you serve up the data or not. But that isn’t a matter of CSP

Comment: Please help me clarify the question... The user is assumed to be a good actor. The bad actor would try to embed my content on 3rd party site in order to trick the user. Thus I was hoping to rely on CSP to protect the user... Does this make sense?

Comment: If a hacker is creating a spoof site, they can effectively make browser requests to you data and show it, *if your data is publicly available*. As I said before, the only way to do what you want is to limit access to users who authenticate— that is: users who log in. This has nothing to do with CSP

Comment: Users are logged in via cookie :) A browser without a cookie gets nothing, there's no public data. I'm trying to secure logged in user's data :)